# BizTalk: Waiting for file written prior to the rest of the orchestration executing

Tags: biztalk

What I am trying to do is ensure that my message is sent to it's destination prior to the rest of the orchestration executing.
My message is large (> 200M), in the orchestration I have the send shape to write the message to a physical location followed by a step to kick off another application to consume the file.
My problem is that this step runs prior to the file send port finishing its writing, and then the application fails to get the file.

I has followed Kent Weare's post:  [BizTalk Delivery Notification](http://kentweare.blogspot.co.nz/2007/11/biztalk-delivery-notification.html) (Thanks Kent Weare), but was unsuccessful.

Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: If the Delivery Notification is not doing the trick then you may have to add a Delay shape in your Orchestration so it waits for a set time first.

Comment: The problem is the rest of orchestration before the send port finish writing file. As I think Delivery Notification is not retrieved yet.
I don't know how long the send port finish its task, so Delay shape can't not be applied.